# How to solve the Error Sql Server Management Studio when Create DB Diagrams(Error in spanish && and error number unknown)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Mensaje de error/ Error Alert Dialog:

> Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)
>
> Detalles/Details
>
> Ubicación del programa:
>
> en Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
>     en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.DatabaseDesignerNode.OnHosted()
>     en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>      en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>      en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>      en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
>      en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.InvokeDesigner(IManagedConnection connection)
>      en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.Invoke()
>      en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolsMenuItemBase.MenuInvokedHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args)

/* I have the 12 version of both sql server and visual studio */

sorry for my english...

Comment: I don't know Spanish, but the top level error seems to say that there was an error encountered trying to write to protected memory. I see this occasionally if I leave it open for too long; try restarting SSMS.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work :( ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem yay :D!!!, the problem was about the installation process.
I only had to replace the files of:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8

with others from another Visual Studio Installation.

I use help from this link, i hope this will be helpful in the future...

Link to the post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa9df00f-49ba-4345-b036-423ae30a5d47/problem-to-create-new-database-diagram-in-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-for-sql-server?forum=sqlexpress